# Remote application options for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server

In our office, the only way to access one of our applications on WiFi or off the LAN is from a MS Terminal Server because of it's high network load. The server is getting old and we are looking for a replacement, preferably a solution that does not require a full blown remote desktop session like TS does.

Linux has X11 forwarding over SSH. If only Windows had this :)

I was looking at VMWare's RDS Hosted Applications in Horizon View. This is a incredibly expensive solution. We are a small business and need only ~10 CALs, and this would set us back ~$3000. Yikes!

What other options are there out there? Anything open source?

Comment: I'm dreaming that some day portwine would be completed and remote X11 options become available for windows too

Comment: It's a shame this question has not received any attention. Just to clarify (so I can hopefully get at least one answer!) the software does not _have_ to be free or open source, but it would be beneficial.

Comment: As far as I know microsoft is principal about now allowing a user to spawn multiple desktop sessions. It is considered server option.

Comment: try using citrix. In old days it worked for me great. http://www.joulupukki.nl/wordpress/?p=292